# how to change imageurl after selection from dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

Hi I have a dropdownlist and id like upon selecting one of the four choices to set the imageurl of Image2 in code behind?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An example. In your markup:

```
< <asp:DropDownList ID="TestDropDownList" runat="server" 
    onselectedindexchanged="TestDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
<asp:ListItem Value="http://url.com/image1.png" Text="Option 1"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="http://url.com/image2.png" Text="Option 2"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="http://url.com/image3.png" Text="Option 3"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="http://url.com/image4.png" Text="Option 4"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:Image ID="TestImage" ImageUrl="" runat="server" />
```

In your code-behind:

```
protected void TestDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Image i = this.TestImage;
        i.ImageUrl = ((DropDownList)sender).SelectedValue;

}
```

Comment: nah not quite what Im looking for, i need the urls for each of the four different selections in the selectvalue to be different

Comment: what i mean is im setting an image on my page based on what is picked in the dropdownlist so each selection is a different imageurl

Comment: @Garrith Graham: Then this code will still work.  Just put the URLs in the values of the options, rather than in the string formatter in code.  Be careful of XSS attacks, though.

Comment: @Garrith Graham - updated the sample to reflect your requirement.

Answer (score 2):

You have to enable AutoPostBack property for the dropdownlist. Then each time a selection changes postback will be send to server, so you codebehind will be executed. If I remeber corectly DropDownList control has an event for changed selection.

Comment: yeah value, its already set to post back I just need it upon which ever one is picked setting the imageurl to something(maunal coding of url)

Answer (score 1):

Add a `OnSelectedIndexChanged` eventhandler, and set `AutoPostBack` to `true`:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="Options" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"
                OnSelectedIndexChanged="Options_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <asp:ListItem Value="Item1">Text 1</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="Item2">Text 2</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

In the code behind you implement the method that handles the event:

```
protected void Options_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string selectedValue = this.Options.SelectedValue;
    ...
}
```